# clang++ compiling template class with implementation in header

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

```
$ make
clang++ -o build/blist.exe  src/driver.cpp src/BList.h -O0 -g -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wextra -Wconversion -Wold-style-cast -std=c++14 -pedantic -Wold-style-cast
clang: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
```

My template implementation is in `BList.cpp`, but `BList.h` includes `BList.cpp`. That's why I pass the header in as an object. I don't know how to set clang to compile!

---

- **My header must be named "BList.h" according to my professor**.
- These parameters compiles with GCC, but not with Clang.

Comment: Why does the header include the source file? And why are you separating away the template implementation?

Comment: @InternetAussie Professor says so!

Comment: While it's not unheard of to place the template implementation in its own file and then include that in the template header, the extension given to those files is usually something like `.tpp` or `.ipp`. The `.cpp` extension is usually given to files which are fed to the compiler, not files meant for inclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with including `BList.cpp` in `BList.h` (though that's a dubious practice by itself).

The problem is that you pass `src/BList.h` to Clang as if it was a source file. The build instruction should be:

```
clang++ -o build/blist.exe  src/driver.cpp -O0 -g -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wextra -Wconversion -Wold-style-cast -std=c++14 -pedantic -Wold-style-cast
```

You should update your makefile accordingly.

Comment: @tambre - While I appreciate the attempt to help. Two points to keep in mind: (1) "as if" and "as though" are equivalent in meaning. I kept your suggestion for simplicity. (2) "makefile" is the technical term, not a mistype.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Not sure why I corrected the "makefile", sorry.